# A tricky definite integral: $\int\limits_0^2 \frac{\sin \left (1-x^2 \right)} {(1-x^2)^2+(1-x^2)^{\frac13}} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here's the **background** of the question sent from a friend:-
“**Source**: a friend(he told that it's a question by an African mathematician)
Answer: don't know”(sic)

The question:-

$$ \mathcal{J} = \int_{0}^{2} \frac{\sin \left (1-x^2 \right)}
{(1-x^2)^2+(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \mathrm{d}x $$

The next 2 lines are potentially dangerous to your problem solving approach to this question. Read at your own risk:-

On the recommendation of @Saulspatz, here's a little context:-
Current Progress:- 
1. Tried basic things like substitution $(1-x^2)$, didn't work out well.
2. Used King's property. Failed.
3. Substituted $\sin(1-x^2)$. Failed to reach anywhere.
4. Trying new things now. 
Now, I can't latex my solution anywhere since I'm not fluent with it. In fact, my friend had to type the code for me to post it here (and I've been told my handwriting is very bad which got my previous question kicked/downvoted out). They don't allow me to post pictures anyways. 
**Relevancy And Motivation& Importance**
“To me:-
Sent this to tons of students & teachers but all in vain. None have been able to solve it. I've been trying for over a month (obviously on and off). Thus, I think it poses to be an interesting question.
To this community:-
It's an challenging integral that's going to bash minds and force them to think of different unique methods solve it"

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Do you want a solution or are you just looking to share?

Comment: @burt dying for a solution here

Comment: @saulspatz I've edited to the best of my ability. Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like Wolfie [timed out](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%281-x%C2%B2%29%2F%5B%281-x%C2%B2%29%C2%B2%2B%281-x%C2%B2%29%5E%281%2F3%29%5D)

Comment: @saulspatz why is my question put on hold? I addressed everything that was requested of me and which was stated in the "reasons behind putting it off topic". The only thing I couldn't address was my approaches to this question due to the amount of time consumed in doing so and the fact that I don't know LaTeX.

Comment: I voted to reopen it, and I didn't vote to close it in the first place.  It needs two more votes to be reopened.  Try to be patient.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh, okay. Sorry. Wasn't actually accusing you of voting to close this question if that's what you're thinking. Thanks for voting to reopen it. Also, I'm new to this aspect of closing questions on stack exchange. I'll be more patient. Apologies again.

Comment: This site uses [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is easier than LaTeX, in my opinion.  Also, one thing that helped me a lot when I first came here is that if you right-click on any formula, and choose "show Math As ... TeX commands" from the popup menu, you'll get another popup with the MathJax.  You can copy and paste it (make sure to surround it with `$` signs) or just inspect it to learn how to format stuff.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for letting me know. This is of great help!

Comment: @YuriyS High schooler here. So "Residues might work, but there's a branch cut." doesn't really hit me.

Comment: @ShreyasJV, you probably should study complex numbers a little (a lot) before attempting such integrals. Note that for $x>1$ you have a cube root of a negative number which is in general complex, because $y^3=-1$ has three solutions

Comment: @YuriyS Studied complex numbers a bit(like to the notion of De Moivre's theorem etc). I suppose you're referring to a concept similar to the cube Roots of unity? I do see your point, though. Considering the limits, it might turn into a complex root in the final answer.

Comment: Yes, the principal branch of the cube root of a negative number is complex, so your integral also will be a complex number. As a more simple example, you can evaluate `Integrate[1/(1-x)^(1/3),{x,0,2}]` in Wolfram Alpha

Comment: @YuriyS checked it out. I think I got the concept and it was fun to understand. I find it poetic to be taught about complex numbers from a person with the most beautiful fractal pattern/set as a profile pic. Thanks so much.

Comment: @saulspatz Umm…I don't mean to trouble you but it's been 2 days?

Comment: I voted to reopen it; there's nothing else I can do.

Comment: Now reposted as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318859/an-african-mathematicians-integral so I guess there's no reason to reopen this.

Comment: Never mind, the repost got closed, so this one may as well stay open.